# How can I run two methods on the one IEnumerable at the same time

Tags: c#, concurrency, ienumerable

Suppose I have

```
void MethodBoth(IEnumerable<int> a){
  Method1(a);
  Method2(a);
}
```

where both `Method1` and `Method2` call a `foreach` on `a`.

The problem here is that `a` will be recreated when passed to `Method2`.  Is there a way to get both methods to run simultaneously?

Suppose that

1. For each i, the i-th entry of `a` will be independent of any external value.
2. Other than that, I do not know how my method would be used, so I assume that `a` is too large to convert to a list and too expensive to get twice.
3. I cannot edit the internals of `Method1` or `Method2`.

Comment: You can't but you can create a second copy (anything else may become pretty complicate)

Comment: You may try to create some IEnumerable wrapper that stores only the current item from the wrapped collection and blocks on any attempt to get the next one until all (registered before) consumers request it. But as @AdrianoRepetti has already said it is nontrivial and easy to do wrong. And it will work well only in this quite specific scenario.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Taking the most literal interpretation of your question, the obvious answer is to execute both methods in separate tasks, so that they run concurrently. As long as the `a` enumerable is thread-safe and can be enumerated multiple times (the latter seems assumable given the question), that should work. If you are okay with the two methods having to operate in lock-step, Eugene's suggestion may work. But without more detail, it's impossible to know for sure what you need.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have updated the question.  Basically I do not know anything about `a` and want to know how to program for the worst case.  I suppose if the programming for the worst case is too difficult, I would have to make some assumptions about `a`.

Answer (score 4):

As proposed in the comments you can use threads and synchronization to achieve this:

```
var consumer1 = new BlockingCollection<int>(boundedCapacity: 1);
var consumer2 = new BlockingCollection<int>(boundedCapacity: 1);
var task1 = Task.Run(() => Method1(consumer1.GetConsumingEnumerable()));
var task2 = Task.Run(() => Method2(consumer2.GetConsumingEnumerable()));

foreach (var item in sourceCollection) {
 consumer1.Add(item);
 consumer2.Add(item);
}

consumer1.CompleteAdding();
consumer2.CompleteAdding();

Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
```

I'm using `BlockingCollection` as a producer consumer handoff point.

Comment: Nicely done. I was trying to do it myself, but it seems I was reinventing the wheel...

Comment: I initially thought I'd have to implement a Haskell style MVar and was going to pass but the BlockingCollection serves as an MVar.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that `M1` is `Method1` and `sourceCollection` is `a`?

Comment: Thanks, this is enough to get me started.  Also by `maxCapacity`, don't you mean `boundedCapacity`?  Also shouldn't it be `BlockingCollection<int>`?

Comment: Yes, yes, yes.......... This is a sketch. You can fill in the holes. I can't save you having to understand how this works. Certainly, don't copy untested code from strangers into your solution :)